# What does “Stream of consciousness airing of grievances” mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was drawn to the phrase, “stream of conscious airing of grievances” appearing in the following passage of the article titled “Trump wages war against the media as demonstrators protest his presidency” in Washington Post (January 21)

> “With Americans taking to the streets in red and blue states alike to
>   emphatically decry a president they consider reprehensible and, even,
>   illegitimate, Trump visited the CIA for a **stream-of-consciousness
>   airing of grievances** — including against journalists.”

www.ndtv.com also wrote;

> Trump visited the Central Intelligence Agency for a
>   **stream-of-consciousness airing of grievances** - including against
>   journalists, whom he called "the most dishonest human beings on
>   earth."

Encyclopedia Britannica defines the stream-of-consciousness as a narrative technique in nondramatic fiction intended to render the flow of myriad impressions—visual, auditory, physical, associative, and subliminal—that impinge on the consciousness of an individual and form part of his awareness along with the trend of his rational thoughts. The term was first used by the psychologist William James in The Principles of Psychology (1890).

I’m curious to know what “Stream of consciousness airing of grievances” used in both Washington Post and www.ndtv articles exactly means.

Are they simply saying that Donald Trump visited CIA for giving his grievance against media in endless and random way or trying to deliver profound implications?

Why did they elaborate to use such an old phrase as introduced in 1890?

Comment: The central distinguishing feature of "stream-of-consciousness" writing is that it is extemporaneous and unplanned—one thought tumbling out after another in ways that are inexplicable by an observer except as "That's what the person thought of next." When I was a high-school student in the U.S. and Canada in the early 1970s, "stream-of-consciousness" was a technique still taught and discussed in English classes, so some U.S. readers won't think of it as an "old phrase." Traditional politicians have great respect for "staying on message" as a rhetorical technique, so when a politician…

Comment: …indulges in a rambling series of thoughts that some hearers interpret as being rather aimless and spur-of-the-moment,  those hearers may search for a style that it resembles, rather than taking it as a normal form of political discourse. The reporters in this instance seem to have settled on “stream of consciousness” as the most apt term to describe the style in question.

Comment: +1 I don't understand the downvotes here. The poster gives context for the question and shows good research from _Encyclopedia Britannica_. I think it's interesting that a phrase that originated as a descriptive term for a specific literary technique evolved into a synonym for "undisciplined and unplanned [remarks or other communication]." It would also be interesting to know when this shift in usage occurred. Thank you for another worthwhile question, Yoichi Oishi.

Comment: You have it right: Trump was complaining about the media in a lengthy and very personal way. Contrast that style of expression with the words in the first article, 'emphatically decry,' which is strong and focused. Also consider the irony of a journalist in the second article reporting on a rambling criticism of journalists.

Answer (score 1):

In comments, Sven Yargs wrote:

> The central distinguishing feature of "stream-of-consciousness" writing is that it is extemporaneous and unplanned—one thought tumbling out after another in ways that are inexplicable by an observer except as "That's what the person thought of next." When I was a high-school student in the U.S. and Canada in the early 1970s, "stream-of-consciousness" was a technique still taught and discussed in English classes, so some U.S. readers won't think of it as an "old phrase." Traditional politicians have great respect for "staying on message" as a rhetorical technique, so when a politician indulges in a rambling series of thoughts that some hearers interpret as being rather aimless and spur-of-the-moment,  those hearers may search for a style that it resembles, rather than taking it as a normal form of political discourse. The reporters in this instance seem to have settled on “stream of consciousness” as the most apt term to describe the style in question.